# How do I solve "Server terminated early with status 127" when running node.js on Linux?

Tags: linux, node.js, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I’m using node 5.10.0 on this version of Linux

```
[davea@mydevbox mydir]$ uname -a
Linux mydevbox.mydomain.com 7.3.8-25.26.amzn1.x86_64 #1 SMP Wed Mar 16 17:15:34 UTC 2016 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

I’m getting the below error when running my script (“Server terminated early with status 127”).  I have verified that I can reach the URL in question using “wget”, so I can’t tell what else I need to make this thing work …

```
[davea@mydevbox mydir]$ node myscript.js 
Validation Complete
/home/davea/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/promise.js:654
    throw error;
    ^

Error: Server terminated early with status 127
    at Error (native)
    at /home/davea/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/remote/index.js:242:20
    at ManagedPromise.invokeCallback_ (/home/davea/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/promise.js:1343:14)
    at TaskQueue.execute_ (/home/davea/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/promise.js:2868:14)
    at TaskQueue.executeNext_ (/home/davea/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/promise.js:2851:21)
    at /home/davea/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/promise.js:2730:27
    at /home/davea/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/promise.js:639:7
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:103:7)
From: Task: WebDriver.createSession()
    at acquireSession (/home/davea/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/webdriver.js:107:22)
    at Function.createSession (/home/davea/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/webdriver.js:337:12)
    at Driver (/home/davea/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/chrome.js:778:38)
    at Builder.build (/home/davea/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/builder.js:464:16)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/home/davea/mydir/js/Optimus.js:14:4)
    at Module._compile (module.js:413:34)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:422:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:357:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:314:12)
    at Module.require (module.js:367:17)
From: Task: WebDriver.navigate().to(http://localhost:8081/myproject)
    at Driver.schedule (/home/davea/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/webdriver.js:386:17)
    at Navigation.to (/home/davea/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/webdriver.js:1029:25)
    at Driver.get (/home/davea/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/webdriver.js:797:28)
    at Object.exports.Login.Page (/home/davea/mydir/js/Optimus.js:505:16)
    at Object.exports.smokeTest (/home/davea/mydir/js/Optimus.js:2442:19)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/home/davea/mydir/SkyNet.js:13:6)
    at Module._compile (module.js:413:34)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:422:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:357:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:314:12)
```

Comment: An exit code of 127 typically means the program couldn't be found (or perhaps a shared library it depends on wasn't found). Are you sure that the path to the chrome browser/driver is correct?

Comment: I have the chromedriver at the same directory level as my script.  Moreover, when I echo $PATH I have "/usr/local/bin:/bin:/usr/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/opt/aws/bin:/home/dalvarado/bin:/usr/lib/chromedriver" so if it needs to be somewhere else, I'd love to know where.

Answer (score 12):

In my case I was missing a Java Runtime environment (JRE). I'm running e2e tests with Selenium in a Debian-based docker image, hence `apt-get install default-jre` did the trick for me. It's a pity selenium doesn't give a more useful error message in this case.

Answer (score 8):

As suggested by other answers, the error message means you have unmet dependencies.

In my case of selenium e2e test, fixes are:

1. `apt-get install default-jre` as mentioned by @Johannes
2. `apt-get -f install` for a fix install
3. `apt-get install chromium-browser` Make sure to install the correct [version](https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/2.33/notes.txt) of chrome related to your chromedriver, e.g. chrome 60-62 for chromedriver 2.33
4. Config webdriver to start chrome in 'headless' mode, as to avoid other unnecessary dependencies. In node it looks like:

`const options = new chromeDriver.Options();
      options.addArguments(
        'headless',
        'disable-gpu',
      );
      new webdriver.Builder()
        .forBrowser('chrome')
        .setChromeOptions(options)
        .build();`

Comment: @AlexanderMills http://chromedriver.chromium.org/downloads Put on your server and have the path configured

Comment: For me `options.addArguments('disable-gpu');` solved the issue

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar issue where it was missing a shared library that I solved by symlinking libnss3.so:

`ln -s /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libnss3.so /usr/lib/libnss3.so`

If the first directory doesn't work for you, find with:

`find /usr/lib/ -name libnss3*`
OR
`find /usr/lib64/ -name libnss3*`

and replace accordingly.

It might also require an update, so try:
`yum update nss`

Comment: I ran "yum update nss" and then ran the first command you listed, but after running that command, I got the error, "ln: failed to create symbolic link ‘/usr/lib/libnss3.so’: File exists"

Comment: Have you tried selenium after that, now that the file exists? If it still doesn't work, then you are not missing libnss3 but something else that I don't know of

Comment: I do get the same error in my question given what I tried from your suggestion.

Answer (score 1):

I was using node.js based selenium script and overcome the issue by installing google chrome manually using the command `curl https://intoli.com/install-google-chrome.sh | bash`

This worked for me. Please give a try. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. I had different versions of chromedriver and google-chrome-stable package in Ubuntu. I checked the chrome version by `google-chrome-stable --version` CLI command. And then downloaded the suitable chromedriver from here: http://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/index.html. Copped it into /usr/bin/local and set 777 permissions to the file. Everything started working.