# Synology NodeJS Selenium - Server terminated early with status 127

Tags: node.js, selenium, debian, synology

I read a lot of similar issue but nothing indicate works ...

I'm on Synology - DSM 7.1 (Debian) and my code is

```
const chrome = require('selenium-webdriver/chrome');
const chromedriver = require('chromedriver');
const webdriver = require('selenium-webdriver');
//const path = require('chromedriver').path;

const {By, until, Builder} = require('selenium-webdriver');

exports.getInfoFromUrl = async(url) => {
    // Lancement du webdriver pour scrapper Bet Assistant
    //let service = new chrome.ServiceBuilder().build();
    //chrome.setDefaultService(service);
    //var driver = new webdriver.Builder(path).withCapabilities(webdriver.Capabilities.chrome()).build();
    
    const options = new chrome.Options();
    options.addArguments(
        '--no-sandbox',
        'headless',
        'disable-gpu',
        '--disable-dev-shm-usage'
    );
    var driver = new webdriver.Builder(chromedriver.path)
      //.forBrowser('chrome')
      .withCapabilities(webdriver.Capabilities.chrome())
      .setChromeOptions(options)
      .build();

    /*chrome.setDefaultService(new chrome.ServiceBuilder(chromedriver.path).build());
    var driver = new webdriver.Builder(chromedriver.path)
                    .setChromeOptions(new chrome.Options().addArguments(['--no-sandbox','-headless', '--disable-dev-shm-usage']))
                    .build();            
        */
    driver.get(url);
}
```

When I execute this code with "node script.js" I get this error :

```
/volume1/web/betassistant/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/remote/index.js:248
                reject(Error(e.message))
                       ^

Error: Server terminated early with status 127
    at /volume1/web/betassistant/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/remote/index.js:248:24
    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:96:5)
```

I try several sample or code to run webdriver but nothing works. I see some of user install "default-jre" ([How do I solve "Server terminated early with status 127" when running node.js on Linux?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36429436/how-do-i-solve-server-terminated-early-with-status-127-when-running-node-js-on)) but I don't have "apt-get" and I think JRE don't be need on DSM.

Some help will be appreciate :)

Comment: Did you find the solution, could you share it?